# Playing audio in Safari using .play()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, safari

I'm looking to play an audio file using custom controls to trigger the .play() method on a custom button. To be clear, I'm not trying to have the audio auto-play. Everything works perfectly in Chrome, but in Safari I get the error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not
> allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context,
> possibly because the user denied permission.

The project is built using React and React Router, so I'm wondering if it's possibly fixable in my useEffect() hook. I've tried enabling controls on the audio element and using CSS to remove them from the DOM, but no luck.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { gsap } from "gsap";

function RadioPlayerNav(props) {
    const audioEl = useRef(null);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

    const playingTitle = document.querySelector(".radio-player-nav .title p");

    const toPX = (value) => {
        return (parseFloat(value) / 100) * (/vh/gi.test(value) ? window.innerHeight : window.innerWidth);
    };

    const radioPlayerGSAP = gsap.to(".radio-player-nav .title p", {
        x: toPX("-5vw"),
        duration: 4,
        ease: "none",
        yoyo: true,
        repeat: -1,
        delay: 1,
        repeatDelay: 1,
        paused: true,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            audioEl.current.play();
            radioPlayerGSAP.play();
            // radioPlayerGSAP.reversed(4, false);
        } else {
            audioEl.current.pause();
        }
    }, [isPlaying]);

    return (
        <div className="radio-player-nav">
            <div className="radio-player-controls">
                <audio src="src/current-radio-mix.mp3" ref={audioEl} preload="auto"></audio>
                <i
                    className={isPlaying ? "fas fa-pause cursor-hover" : "fas fa-play cursor-hover"}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
                    }}
                ></i>
                <div className="title">
                    <p>MIXED FEELINGS M0001</p>
                </div>
                <a href="src/current-radio-mix.mp3" download="Mixed Feelings M0001">
                    <i className="fas fa-download cursor-hover"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RadioPlayerNav;
```

You can find the full github repo for the project here: https://github.com/nallstott/mixed-feelings/tree/master

Answer (score 5):

Turns out, safari requires you to use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect to accomplish this. I'm leaving the post up since I didn't see anything previously that gave the answer, along with the article that solved it for me in case anyone else has this issue with `<audio>` on safari.

https://lukecod.es/2020/08/27/ios-cant-play-youtube-via-react-useeffect/

Answer (score -1):

I also play audio in my app, and it cycles through them. I was able to get around this by placing my audio files in a map, and use a separate function to call the audio to play.

```
import hold_female from '../../assets/audio/Female/hold_female.mp3';
import exhale_female from '../../assets/audio/Female/exhale_female.mp3';
import inhale_female from '../../assets/audio/Female/inhale_female.mp3';
import hold_male from '../../assets/audio/Male/hold_male.mp3';
import exhale_male from '../../assets/audio/Male/exhale_male.mp3';
import inhale_male from '../../assets/audio/Male/inhale_male.mp3';

//Props here...

createAudio('Exhale_female', exhale_female); //These place the audio into a map under the name provided.
createAudio('Inhale_female', inhale_female);
createAudio('Hold_female', hold_female);
createAudio('Exhale_male', exhale_male);
createAudio('Inhale_male', inhale_male);
createAudio('Hold_male', hold_male);

const BreatheTest: FC<BreathingProps> = ({ gender }) => {
  const [stageText, setStageText] = useState<string>('Inhale');
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [milliseconds, setMilliseconds] = useState<number>(0); //Set to 0 so the audio plays right away and there is no delay.

  const captions = ['Inhale', 'Hold', 'Exhale', 'Hold'];

  const playAudioFiles = () => { 
    playAudio(`${stageText}_${gender}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      stopAll(); //stop all the previous audio files if they are running.
      setStageText(captions[index]);
      setIndex(index === 3 ? 0 : index + 1);
      setMilliseconds(isSafari ? 4500 : 4350);//Sets the timeout to the time of the audio files.
      playAudioFiles(); //Plays the audio files as the useEffect runs
    }, milliseconds);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [index]);

 //... render method and everything else.

}
```

My app is for controlling breathing, and this is how I have gotten past the error you are seeing. From what I have read, iOS just requires some kind of trigger to start any media, audio or video. Putting the play function into a series of play functions kind of satisfies Safari.

It may not work for you, or how your code works, but if this is where we can discuss how we got around iOS's audio control, this is another way.